# How to stop the tracking data from Addthis to Google Analytics

Tags: addthis

Some times ago, I have installed Addthis in a my site.

For send event to Google Analytics about the action of sharing with Facebook, Twitter and others social network, I had put these variables in the config variable for initialize the AddThis object

```
,data_ga_property: 'xxx' //code for site in analytics
,data_ga_social: true
```

Now, I need to stop the tracking data from Addthis to Google Analytics.
Then, I had changed these variables in this way

```
,data_ga_property: '' //code for site in analytics
,data_ga_social: false
```

But, even if I have changed these variables the tracking of the data seems to be not stopped.

Indeed, I can see in the console of Google Analytics that it is still receiving the event about social network.

What can I do to stop this tracking definitely?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: **TYPO** alert: it's **Analytics** - not "Analitycs"  .... (the `y` comes first - then a `i` - not the other way around)

Comment: Thanks. My english is very bad. Sorry for that.